# Почему первое число не добавляется в массив?

Tags: python, python-3.x

при выполнении приведенного ниже кода в массив не добавляется самое первое значение i. Я не понимаю почему? Объясните кто может пожалуйста.введите сюда код

```
i = int(input())
lst = []
while i !=0:
        i = int(input())
        lst.append(i)
print((lst))
```

Comment: оно "не добавляется" потому что вы его не добавляете. где у вас добавление числа после первого input?

Comment: Поменяйте местами строки внутри цикла. Сейчас у вас первое не добавляется, зато добавляется последний `0`, который, скорее всего, не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Сам сидел тупил и не понимал в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

у вас первая строка кода, создает переменную (i) и не куда ее не записывает, уберите первую строку измените условия выхода из цикла и код будет валиден, как вы хотите

```
lst = []
while True:
        i = int(input())
        lst.append(i)
        if i == 0:
            break
print((lst))
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать первую строку, запустить код - увидите насколько такой код валиден)

Comment: ну я добавил, пример...

Comment: Но поясняющий текст все еще некорректен

Comment: я честно говоря думал и так понятно

Comment: Представьте, что человеческий текст - это программный код. Передаем этот код какому-то исполнителю, он один в один исполняет его, получает ошибку. Вывод - этот код (текст) некорректен. У вас еще и человеческий "код" не соответствует программному коду.